# write a recursive funktion that calculates the remainder r when n >= 0 is divided by d > 0

Tags: matlab, function, math

I have written this

```
function r = remainder(n,d) % n>=0, d>0
    if d == 0
    r = 0;
    else
    r = rem(n,d);
    end
end
```

but it's not a recursive function

Comment: I believe this question assumes to do it without using the built-in `rem()` (remainder) function.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if this breaks down anywhere, but I'm sure with some testing and logical overview that can be validated. Here is a function that calls itself repeatedly to find the remainder after division. This breaks down the `rem()` remainder function into a recursive subtraction by the divisor until the remaining residual amount is smaller than the divisor. They're some additional guard if-statements for the cases with involving a divisor or number of 0.

### Function Call:

```
Find_Remainder(4,5)
```

### Function:

```
function [Remainder] = Find_Remainder(Number,Divisor)

if(Divisor > 0)

if(Number >= Divisor)
Remainder = Number - Divisor;

if(Remainder >= Divisor)
%Recursively calling the "Find_Remainder() function%
[Remainder] = Find_Remainder(Remainder,Divisor);
end

end

if(Number < Divisor)
Remainder = Number;
end
end

end
```

### Test Script for Checking:

```
clc;
Number = 91;
Divisor = 71;

Find_Remainder(Number,Divisor)
rem(Number,Divisor)
```

**Ran using MATLAB R2019b**

Comment: @LukasFörström No, problem happy to help. :)

Answer (score 1):

If we use `abs`, we can create a shorter recursive function that work with `n,d ∈ ℤ`:

```
function r = reminds(n,d)
    x = abs(n)-abs(d);
    if x < 0
        r = n;
    else
        reminds(x*sign(n),d)
    end
end
```

Noticed that the `sign` of `d` doesn't matter. Only the `sign` of the number `n` matter. `rem(10,-3)` and `rem(10,3)` both output `1`.

---

If `n,d ∈ R` the function is even simpler:

```
function r = reminds(n,d)
    if n-d < 0
        r = n;
    else
        reminds(n-d,d)
    end
end
```